# Get-ChildItem not finding files

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to recursively find files in folders, I have gotten the file names into an Array but the Get-ChildItem doesn't find the files.  I can replace the $ImageNames variable with an actual string name and it finds them.  So I know there is something wrong with the variable, but I can't pinpoint what it is.  Here is a snip of the script.

I have tried to break the array into a foreach, but I get the same result with the single string.

```
Current output of $ImageNames from Write-Output of $imageNames
TEST_###_DPm.X.1.2.840.113681.2886735633.1532516094.5056.994912425400525861.dcm
TEST_###_DPm.X.1.2.840.113681.2886735633.1532516094.5056.996112425422850002.dcm
TEST_###_DPm.X.1.2.840.113681.2886735633.1532516094.5056.997312425470276903.dcm
```

Updated per advice, but still not working

```
foreach ($xmlFile in $sumReportArray)
    {

        $outputDirectory = $patientDir
        $subDirPerXML = Split-Path -Path $xmlFile -Leaf -Resolve
        $finalDir = $outputDirectory + '\' + $subDirPerXML
        [xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content $xmlFile

        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $finalDir | Out-Null
        $imageNames = $XmlDocument.VOLPARA_SERVER_INTERFACE.VolparaDicomSummaryReport.VolparaInputs.Image | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ImageFileName 
        Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $volparaPath -include $imageNames -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination $finalDir
    }
```

Here is the error I get...

> ```
> Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path.
> At C:\Users\AdamZenner\OneDrive - Volpara Health Technologies Limited\1 Volpara\Production Software\Script_VolparaServerSearch\VolparaServerSearch_1.0.ps1:90 char:13
> +             Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path ($volparaPath) -filter ($ima ...
> +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\Program File...araServer\DATA\:String) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
> ```

Comment: Don't put your variables inside brackets `()` Also show us what `$volpAraPath` contains

Comment: I removed the brackets and still get the same result.  
$volparaPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Matakina\VolparaServer\DATA\'

Comment: If would be helpful if you would [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56084214/edit) your question to give an example of the contents of `$imageNames`.

Comment: Output added for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `... | Select ImageFileName | Out-String` contains unnecessary strings. (Header, Separator, etc.)

So you should use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`.

```
$imageNames = … | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ImageFileName
```

But in this case it is enough to use dot access.

and if `$imageNames` is an array, use `-Include` parameter instead of `-Filter` parameter.

```
$imageNames = $XmlDocument.VOLPARA_SERVER_INTERFACE.VolparaDicomSummaryReport.VolparaInputs.Image.ImageFileName
Get-ChildItem -Path $volparaPath -Include $imageNames -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination $finalDir
```

Comment: Alright, so this helped, except it copied EVERYTHING from the sub directories.  Before it didn't copy anything, and now using -Include it copied ALL files and folders??  In the Array there are strings like image1.dcm, image2.dcm, in the subfolder there are a couple of files that I want it to grab.  The exact name image2.dcm and an information file called image2.dcm.out.  Can you help with that?

Comment: Additionally the XML value that I am pulling is an attribute not the <a>Value</a>, does that help?

Comment: Fixed `-LiteralPath` to `-Path`.

Comment: I think that there is no problem even if it is an attribute.

Comment: There wasn't but, you put VOLPARA_SERVER_INTERFACE.VolparaDicomSummaryReport.VolparaInputs.Image.ImageFileName and I had to change it to VOLPARA_SERVER_INTERFACE.VolparaDicomSummaryReport.VolparaInputs.Image.  It wasn't getting any values.

Comment: Change `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath …` to `Get-ChildItem -Path …`.
and If you can not get the value from xml, please show xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the parenthesis () from all your variables and it should work.

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path ($finalDir)
```

to

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $finalDir
```

Comment: Same here, I still get the same Error.